# Can't turn Kotlin "declaration platform type" warning into an error

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a simple Kotlin function which is calling some Java code:

```
fun simpleSchema(field: GraphQLFieldDefinition) =
    newSchema()
        .query(newObject()
            .name("root")
            .field(field)
            .build())
        .build()
```

Inside my IDEA, namely

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5
Build #IU-162.2228.15, built on October 14, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-287-b2 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

there is a helpful message:

```
Declaration has platform type. Make the type explicit to prevent subtle bugs.
This inspection reports functions and properties that have platform type. 
In order to prevent unexpected errors, the type should be declared explicitly.
```

which is great.  But on the RHS of the editor pane this message is colored as a Weak Warning and I want it to be an Error.  I go to Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Kotlin -> "Function or property has platform type" and mark it as an error.

Why does this not work?  Searching for "platform type" in the inspections shows no more likely candidate than the above.  I have restarted and invalidated the caches...

[image: Code in question]
[image: Tooltip for Alt-Enter]

Comment: press alt+enter on this suggestion. In popup you can easily find real declaration/inspection name. For example "Fix all 'Unused symbol' problems in file". `Unused symbol` - is declaration name in my case. Got it?

Comment: I've added some images to my question.  For neither "Add non-null.." nor "Specify return type..." in the popup can I find applicable Inspections in the settings, so I am still at a loss...

Comment: I have different (http://imgur.com/VpVHHan), maybe this can help

Comment: Interesting, yours says "Specify type explicitly" and mine says "Specify return type explicitly" and when I follow mine I get a popup showing just `GraphQLSchema?` and `Any`.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio, not regular intellij and compiling to java, maybe your ide configured for use with js

Comment: I think marking warnings as errors is not supported by the Kotlin plugin, yet. Regarding the quickfix: There is a bug preventing `GraphQLSchema` from being one of the candidates. You can track it here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12633